# Implementation of BeforeEach within a single method

Tags: java, junit5

My project has a DataSource class that implements the database connection parameters, as well as the initialization of the database connection:

```
public class DataSource {
    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource ds;
 
    public static HikariDataSource getDataSource() {
        if (ds == null) {
            config.setJdbcUrl(System.getProperty("jdbcUrl","jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres"));
            config.setUsername(System.getProperty("jdbcUser","postgres"));
            config.setPassword(System.getProperty("jdbcPassword","postgres"));
            ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
 
            initDatabase();
        }
        return ds;
    }
 
    private static void initDatabase() {
        try {
            DatabaseConnection connection = new JdbcConnection(ds.getConnection());
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(connection);
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(
                    System.getProperty("liquibaseFile","liquibase.xml"),
                    new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(),
                    database);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts());
        } catch (SQLException | LiquibaseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
 
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

The JUnit library is used to develop unit tests for project dao methods. A base class has been created with the help of which the parameters for connecting to the database are redefined (in this case, to H2):

```
public class Base {
 
    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("jdbcUrl", "jdbc:h2:mem:test_" + UUID.randomUUID());
        System.setProperty("jdbcUser", "sa");
        System.setProperty("jdbcPassword", "");
        System.setProperty("liquibaseFile", "liquibase_test.xml");
    }
 
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        setup();
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that System.setProperty properties are redefined within a single method? It is important that the behavior of the method is similar to that of @BeforeEach instead of the @BeforeAll annotation.
I tried to put @BeforeEach instead of @BeforeAll, removing static, but when the test is executed, the postgress database is accessed, and not H2, as required by the condition.

Comment: Perhaps something is calling `DataSource.getDataSource()` before junit calls `setup()`. You can add some logging to check this. It isn't clear why you have written the `init` method. Why do you think that `init` will have any effect? Do you understand how your `DataSource.getDataSource()` method works? That `ds` is `static` and that it will only call `initdatabase()` once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using system properties to configure the database make your classore easily configurable and testable. You could implement a singleton pattern and an initializing method for example.

Having said that, using a different database for production than for testing may not reproduce the exact behavior.

Comment: Never did anything like that. Could you show with an example?

Comment: This exceeds a Stackoverlow answer. You can search for Java Singleton Testing and find lots of articles. For example https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to configure a different datasource for tests. This can be done without any code just by providing a different `application.properties` file.

Assuming your `application.properties` are in the `src/main/resources`. Make a copy of it and put it in the folder `src/test/resources`. In this file you can modify the properties for the tests. They will be found only by the tests. Application will still use the original file.

Comment: According to the condition of the assignment, implementation is required in one method, without the use application.properties.

That is, from these two methods to make one.
`    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {...}
 
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {...}`